# Interacting between two pieces of Swift code (Apple ARKit sample code)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Apple has posted some sample code for "Creating Face-Based AR Experiences" [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences).

My question deals with passing a variable between two sections of code.  In RobotHead.swift I would like to detect a condition within blendShapes, and somehow pass it back to ViewController.swift so code in the ViewController can react to that condition.  What is the simplest way to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: Start by including relevant code in your question (as text). And don't just post both swift files. Just post the relevant parts.

Comment: RobotHead isn’t where the blendShapes originally come from. Those come from face anchors vended by the ARSession to its delegate, and the session is owned by the view controller. You don’t have to propagate that data back up to the view controller if you can arrange your architecture so that the view controller has that data in the first place.

Comment: (Remember, there’s nothing sacrosanct about the way any given sample code project, Apple’s or otherwise, divides responsibility between classes. It just reflects the opinion of that project’s authors on how best to do the things that code is doing. But you’re a different author, and you’re probably doing different things.)

Comment: @rickster So what I'd like to do is inside RobotHead.swift's blendShapes method, call something like super.action(forKey: "value").  And then in ViewController.swift define func action (key:String) { //do something }.  This seems simple, but I must be thinking about it wrong. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is create a public function in your `ViewController` class, pass your view controller to `VirualContentUpdater`, and then call the method from its `renderer(:didUpdate:for)` function.

In `ViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    contentUpdater.viewController = self
    /* ... */
}

public func update(withFaceAnchor anchor: ARFaceAnchor) {
    // do something with anchor.blendShapes
}
```

In `VirtualContentUpdater.swift`

```
public var viewController: ViewController?
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    viewController?.update(withFaceAnchor: anchor)
    /* ... */
}
```